# Why does the script think this Vector3 position is a player?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to finish a gun script for a game, and I have scrapped many things. This time, I thought I could finish the script. But then, when I checked output it said that I was trying to use an Instance when I should be using a Vector3. When I looked at it, I soon realized that the script thought it was a player. WHAT IS HAPPENING?

```
script.Parent.Shoot.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(posofm) --I am using a LocalScript to get the position of the mouse (mouse.Hit.Position)
    bullet = Instance.new("Part")
    bullet.Parent = workspace
    bullet.Size = Vector3.new(0.3,0.3,1)
    bullet.BrickColor = BrickColor.Yellow()
    bullet.Position = script.Parent.Handle.Position
    bullet.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(bullet.Position,posofm)
    bullet.Velocity = bullet.CFrame.LookVector * 90
end)
```

Comment: The LocalScript is activating a function when the Tool it is parented to is activated. It then fires a RemoteEvent giving the ServerScript the position of the mouse.

Comment: I managed to find a way, but I had to use multiple useless variables and it felt cluttered with the variables. Basically, I had to make 4 VARIABLES just for the position of the mouse.  Can we get some Fs in the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for [RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RemoteEvent/OnServerEvent). The first argument provided to the connection is always the Player that called [RemoteEvent:FireServer()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteEvent/FireServer).

For example :

```
-- when a LocalScript calls FireServer :
event:FireServer(a, b, c)

-- the server Script receives :
event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, a, b, c) ... end)
```

So in your case, even though the variable is named `posofm`, since it is the first argument in the list, it represents the Player object. And the actual position of the mouse  is ignored because there's no argument in the function to store it.

So to fix it, all you need to do is add an argument in the connection to represent the player and properly label your arguments :

```
script.Parent.Shoot.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, posofm)
```